# Http Callout from Apache Tomcat

Tags: force.com, webservices, httpcalloutmock, httprequest

I am trying to access a webservice hosted on localhost from salesforce with the following url:
"localhost:8080/HttpCalloutSalesforce/list"

But it's not working and I am getting the below error message :

```
ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved


ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved


While trying to process the request:

GET /HttpCalloutSalesforce/list?id=0019000000L9MNVAA3 HTTP/1.0
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
SFDC_STACK_DEPTH: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
User-Agent: SFDC-Callout/28.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Via: 1.1 proxy-tyo.net.salesforce.com:8080 (squid)
X-Forwarded-For: 10.238.12.22
Cache-Control: max-age=259200
Connection: keep-alive
```

Can anyone please confirm whether salesforce support Http Callout from localhost or not ?

Comment: If you've developed a webservice running on Tomcat and you are trying to call it from Salesforce... is the Tomcat instance running on your local machine? Open up a port and call it by IP address rather than as localhost.

Comment: @DougB did you mean a LAN IP or a public internet IP?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do callouts to localhost. Salesforce is hosted in the cloud and has no knowledge of your local network. You need to provide a public url for Salesforce to hit.

Comment: so, Is there any online free web-service hosting server where I can host my webservice and test callout ?

Comment: You'll either need to use a sandbox setup for the service you're using, or you could fake it quite quickly and easily using Heroku and Node.js.